# Что происходит с лимитом 200 и знаками, связанные с ним, при пересчёте?

Tags: поддержка, знаки, репутация

Есть несколько событий, в том числе пара необычных:

```
-37   Голосование исправлено (подробнее)
 -8   перенесён
+10   голос «за»
```

На странице репутации отображение минусов, связанных с переносом, регулируется флажком

> показать удалённые сообщения

Соответственно, можно увидеть либо -27, либо -35.

В верхнем меню всегда показывается -27.

1. Увеличивают ли эти пересчёты 200-бальный дневной лимит?
2. Как в таких случаях будут рассчитываться 200 баллов для знаков [Академик](//ru.stackoverflow.com/help/badges/41/mortarboard), [Эпопея](//ru.stackoverflow.com/help/badges/42/epic) и [Легенда](//ru.stackoverflow.com/help/badges/43/legendary)?

[image: скриншот]

Answer (score 2):

1. Насколько я знаю, лимит (суточный) остается прежний. Т.е. если уже есть минус 50 реп за сегодня, то можно максимум собрать 250 реп голосами (за вопросы или ответы). В итоге всё равно будет 200. (Лично с такой ситуацией не сталкивался, могу ошибаться)
2. Знаки или прогресс по знакам, полученные за 200+ суточных реп не откатываются. Изменения репутации при пересчете затрагивают уже новый день. Полученные ранее 200+ считаются честными. (Проверено на личном опыте)

Comment: 2. Это я знаю, я другое спросил. Вот есть -8 за удаление - получается, надо набрать 208 (т. е. после вычитания этих 8 получится 200), чтобы день засчитался в знаке, или достаточно 200 (т. е. реальное изменение идёт только на 192)? И такой же вопрос по откату. 3. Баллы за удаление пользователя в лимит не входят: я вчера получил 200 (лимит) + 15 (принятый ответ) + 2 (за удалённого пользователя).

Comment: @Qwertiy если суточный прирост <200, то никаких знаков не будет. Т.е. смотрим на график репутации в профиле, и кол-во превышений 200 есть прогресс по знаку Легенда.

Comment: Там внизу флажок "показать удалённые сообщения" - от него зависит значение на графике.

Comment: @Qwertiy у меня значение на графике не зависит от галочки (есть только один случай удалённого ответа с голосами). В любом случае - чекбокса нет при просмотре репутации другого участника, на это значение и надо полагаться.

Comment: А какое из них там? У меня за вчера 7 или 15?

Comment: @Qwertiy 15. Но можно было в инкогнито и самому посмотреть :)

Comment: Да, что-то не подумал :)